# How to calculate exposure time from a maximum and minimum value, every minute based on time of day in python

Tags: python, math, raspberry-pi

I want to make my [Raspberry Pi camera timelapse boxes](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4fEfDcAfXs1-mImgHuLwOw) to take long exposures at night, and shorter exposures at day. I've gathered a list of sunset and sunrises for my location [like this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ekstremedia/raspberry-timelapse/master/scripts/solartimes.json) ([Script here](https://github.com/ekstremedia/raspberry-timelapse/blob/master/scripts/solar.py))

It has the time of day where sun rises, noon and sets. (Or the value "sun": never_rises, or never_sets for polar winter and polar summer, where I live.)

My Picamera has max 6s exposure, so 6000000 microseconds, to get usable images at night. In daytime, i get a good exposure around 4000 microsecond exposure.

I want to make a script that calculates exposure time from **max**: 6000000 to **min**: 4000 based on the current time, every minute.

Im thinking something like: Below the time, and until 2 hours before sunrise, its dark, = **max** exposure.

In 2 hours from sunrise, to daylight, get a value from **max** to **min**.

**min** continues trough the day.

Then, from **min** to **max** in two hours, from sunset and outwards, when its dark again.

But my math skills are weak. How could I calculate a smooth transition from **max** to **min** each minute, during two hours?

If the sun set and rise was the same time every day, I could make a excel sheet to get usable values, but as the sun set and rises at different times every day it gets tricky.

Scripts used to make the timelapses can be found [here](https://github.com/ekstremedia/raspberry-timelapse).

Comment: What are the step sizes for your exposure? 1 microsecond?

Comment: I dont know, its the pi camera v2, and have not found any info on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This takes some time to run, so there may be a better way to implement it. It assumes 1 microsecond steps for exposure times, so if it is different, just modify the `np.linspace` line.

I have it starting at the max exposure, 2 hours before sunrise exposure begins to linearly decrease to the min value at sunrise. At sunset it begins to linearly increase to the max value at 2 hours past sunset. If the time between sunset and sunrise was less than 4 hours, I decided to scale the max exposure based on the time difference. There might be better outcomes using different scales (i.e. log or geometric), but that might come more from experimentation than the coding itself.

Personally, I think the timing assumptions are a little off, but that's more a question of appropriate exposure settings based on time of day than the question posed here and the script can be adjusted as such.

```py
import requests
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import plotly.graph_objects as go

max = 6000000
min = 4000
change = np.round(np.linspace(min, max, 121))
mins = pd.DataFrame({"time": pd.date_range("1/1/2021", "31/12/2021", freq="T"), "exposure": max})
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ekstremedia/raspberry-timelapse/master/scripts/solartimes.json"
data = requests.get(url).json()
sunset = None
neversets = False
for i in data:
    if not data[i]["data"]:
        if data[i]["sun"] == "never_sets":
            day = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'2021-{i}', "%Y-%d-%m")
            day_end = day + datetime.timedelta(hours=23, minutes=59)
            mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= day) & (mins["time"] <= day_end), "exposure"] = min
            if not neversets:
                new_max = int((((day-sunset).seconds/120)/120)*max)
                new_change = np.linspace(min, new_max, int(((day-sunset).seconds/120))+1)
                new_change_a = np.round(np.concatenate([new_change[:-1], new_change[::-1]]))
                try:
                    mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= sunset) & (mins["time"] <= day), "exposure"] = new_change_a
                except ValueError:
                    new_change_a = np.round(np.concatenate([new_change, new_change[::-1]]))
                    mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= sunset) & (mins["time"] <= day), "exposure"] = new_change_a
            neversets = True
    else:
        sunrise = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'2021-{i} {data[i]["sunrise"]}', "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M")
        pre_sunrise = sunrise - datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
        if neversets:
            day = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'2021-{i}', "%Y-%d-%m")
            sunrise = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'2021-{i} {data[i]["sunrise"]}', "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M")
            new_max = int((((sunrise-day).seconds/120)/120)*max)
            new_change = np.linspace(min, new_max, int(((sunrise-day).seconds/120))+1)
            new_change_a = np.round(np.concatenate([new_change[:-1], new_change[::-1]]))
            try:
                mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= day) & (mins["time"] <= sunrise), "exposure"] = new_change_a
            except ValueError:
                new_change_a = np.round(np.concatenate([new_change, new_change[::-1]]))
                mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= day) & (mins["time"] <= sunrise), "exposure"] = new_change_a
            sunset = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'2021-{i} {data[i]["sunset"]}', "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M")
            post_sunset = sunset + datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
            mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= sunrise) & (mins["time"] <= sunset), "exposure"] = min
            mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= sunset) & (mins["time"] <= post_sunset), "exposure"] = change
            neversets = False
            continue
        if sunset:
            yest_sunset = sunset
            if sunrise-yest_sunset < datetime.timedelta(hours=4):
                new_max = int((((sunrise-yest_sunset).seconds/120)/120)*max)
                new_change = np.linspace(min, new_max, int(((sunrise-yest_sunset).seconds/120))+1)
                new_change_a = np.round(np.concatenate([new_change[:-1], new_change[::-1]]))
                try:
                    mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= yest_sunset) & (mins["time"] <= sunrise), "exposure"] = new_change_a
                except ValueError:
                    new_change_a = np.round(np.concatenate([new_change, new_change[::-1]]))
                    mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= yest_sunset) & (mins["time"] <= sunrise), "exposure"] = new_change_a
                sunset = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'2021-{i} {data[i]["sunset"]}', "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M")
                post_sunset = sunset + datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
                mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= sunrise) & (mins["time"] <= sunset), "exposure"] = min
                mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= sunset) & (mins["time"] <= post_sunset), "exposure"] = change
                continue

        sunset = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'2021-{i} {data[i]["sunset"]}', "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M")
        post_sunset = sunset + datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
        mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= pre_sunrise) & (mins["time"] <= sunrise), "exposure"] = change[::-1]
        mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= sunrise) & (mins["time"] <= sunset), "exposure"] = min
        mins.loc[(mins["time"] >= sunset) & (mins["time"] <= post_sunset), "exposure"] = change

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergl(x=mins["time"], y=mins["exposure"], mode='lines'))
fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=True)
fig.show()

current = datetime.datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
print(mins.loc[mins["time"] == current, "exposure"])
```

This was actually sort of fun to figure out. I hope it works.

Comment: When that script of yours first loaded it blew me away, that was just fantastic. What I need is to run a script that returns me the actual value for the current datetime.now(), so I can use that value in the photo-taking script, but I can probably derivate that from the script you made, will explore it further after work, thanks alot!

Comment: I added a few lines for that. I would definitely suggest, if this isn't already how you do it, to have the chart generation only run once - even run it off the pi, and just pickle the chart or something - and just pull values from it as you go.